# Javascript array with double as index

Tags: javascript, arrays, double

I've just been looking into JavaScript and have read that JS technically does not have integers, instead using doubles. This led me to the question of how JS handles array positions.

What would happen in the following scenario?:

```
let foo[] = {'x','y','z'}
var bar = foo[1.5]
```

What would the value of `bar` be in this scenario? My assumption would be that `Math.floor` would be applied to 1.5, but I couldn't find anything that states this, and you know what they say about assumptions.

Edit: Syntax update for future viewers:

```
let foo = ['x','y','z']
var bar = foo[1.5]
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: But of course, you'd have to fix it first. `let foo[] = {'x','y','z'}` isn't valid javascript

Comment: @pilchard that's not true. `var foo = {'1.5' : 2};` and then `var bar = foo[1.5]'` works in my browser

Comment: Technically Javascript has no indexes, everything is a property name. Even the index of an array is just the number that converted to string property such as `"1"`. So `foo[1.5]` is just looking for a property name called `"1.5"` in `foo` object which is `undefined` by default unless you assigned it.

Answer (score 2):

`let foo[] = {'x', 'y', 'z'}` is not a valid JavaScript syntax.
If you want to create an array with 'x', 'y' and 'z', you need to use: `let foo = ['x', 'y', 'z'];`.

Anyway, the value of `bar` will be `undefined`:

```js
let foo = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var bar = foo[1.5];
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm new to JS so thanks for the cleanup there too.
What if we do the opposite?
`foo[1.5] = somevalue`

Comment: In the scenario 
`foo[1.5] = 'bar';
console.log(foo[1.5]);`
The output would be `bar`. Answered my own question by testing.

Answer (score 2):

In the scenario you provided, assuming the correct syntax is:

```
let foo = ['x','y','z'] 
var bar = foo[1.5]
```

then bar will be equal to 'undefined'. It will only return one of the array values if you enter a proper integer value, such as 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: This is actually not true. It can and does return array values of non-integer numbers such as 1.5, but the instantiation of the array assigns x, y and z the values of 0, 1 and 2 respectively. 'foo[1.5] = x' works just fine and will return 'x' if we 'console.log(foo[1.5])'